# parsing XSD with ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, xsd

Hi i have a XSD that i want to parse. Note that i don't want validate it against a XML but get all enumerations that i have there. For example

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsd:simpleType name="fruitNames">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:enumeration value="banana" />
  <xsd:enumeration value="apple" />
  <xsd:enumeration value="orange" />
  <xsd:enumeration value="mango" />
 </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I want to extract the enumeration values.. any idea? I tried to play with XSD::Schema but without success..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSD is just a flavour of XML so you can use REXML e.g.

```
require 'rexml/document'
doc = REXML::Document.new(File.new('yourfile.xsd'))
values = doc.elements.to_a('//xsd:enumeration').map { |el| el.attributes['value'] }
=> ["banana", "apple", "orange", "mango"]
```

Comment: yup, i figured out some hours ago :-)

Comment: Note there are some issues with this approach:

1. You don't close the file properly
2. this will break as soon as there is another enum, better use something like //xsd:simpleType[@name="fruitNames"]//xsd:enumeration

Answer (score 2):

Code sample:

```
require 'rexml/document'

doc = REXML::Document.new(DATA.read)

REXML::XPath.each(doc, '//xsd:simpleType[@name="fruitNames"]//xsd:enumeration/@value') do |e|
  puts e.value
end

__END__
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsd:simpleType name="fruitNames">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:enumeration value="banana" />
  <xsd:enumeration value="apple" />
  <xsd:enumeration value="orange" />
  <xsd:enumeration value="mango" />
 </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```